# initializing pointer to array with two different constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, constructor, initialization

I have a program in which i want to initialize an array of class objects using pointer.

```
class xyz{};
cin>>M;

xyz *a=new xyz[M];   //this will call the constructor for each object.
```

the problem is that i have two constructor in class xyz. i want to initialize last two element using other constructor, not the default one with no arguments.
how can i do this?

i want M+1'th and M+2'th term to be initialized by different constructor that accepts argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `cin<<M` is wrong.  It should be `cin >> M`.  Make sure your insertion and extraction operators are pointing the correct direction.

You cannot with single indirection.  The `new` operator will call the default constructor for each object in the array.

Options for how to reach your goal are:  copy the default value you want over the desired allocation, or create an array of pointers to objects.

**Copy Method**

```
xyz t(my_other_constructor);
xyz* a = new xyz[M];
a[M - 1] = t; // overwrite the default constructed value with the desired
```

**Double Indirection**

```
xyz** a = new xyz*[M];
for (int i = 0; i < M - 1; ++i)
{
    a[i] = new xyz;
}
a[M - 1] = new xyz(my_other_constructor);
```

Ideally, you would use `std::vector` instead of creating manual arrays, though.

Comment: oops, dont worry i have wrote cin>>M in my program. my bad i wrote it wrong here.

Comment: trying double indirection now

Answer (score 4):

```
std::vector<xyz> a(M-2);
a.push_back(xyz(...));     // xyz(...) here is a call to the
a.push_back(xyz(...));     // constructor you want to use
```

This code assumes that M >= 2.  This is, of course, not a safe assumption, and you will have to decide how to handle non-conforming cases.